# In a WPF TextBox, why does an inactive selection appear incorrectly when scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

In a WPF `TextBox`, if I:

- set `IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled` to `True`
- allow horizontal scrolling
- type sufficient characters so that I need to scroll the
  text box to see them all

The selection highlighting works fine as long as the textbox has focus/is active. However, once it loses focus (but the selection highlight remains due to the `IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled` being set to true), and if I scroll the text box using the scrollbar, the highlight does not scroll with the text. This essentially means the highlight is now highlighting different characters. If I hit tab to regain focus, the highlight correctly adjusts to highlight the correct characters again.

I can reproduce this very simply, by creating a WPF Desktop App (any .Net framework should be fine), and using this XAML within the Window tag:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="50" Width="100" TextWrapping="NoWrap" IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="Hello" />
        <TextBox Height="50" Width="100" TextWrapping="NoWrap" IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="World" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

With the above layout, just type sufficient characters to make one of the textbox show a scrollbar. Then highlight some characters at the start of that textbox. Then change focus to the other textbox. Then scroll the original textbox and you'll see the selection highlight different/incorrect characters. (You have to look closely since the inactive highlight is a very subtle effect with the default definition).

In other words, the selection highlight does not take the scroll position into account when the textbox is inactive.

I can't imagine this is the intended behavior. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Since no one has an answer to this, my guess is that it's just a bug in WPF unfortunately.